# what is meaning of "mapping backed by a file" in linux kernel?

Tags: memory-management, process, linux-kernel

I an newbie in linux, I didnt get proper meaning of "mapping backed by a file"  in process address space

can anybody explain?

Answer (score 1):

It means that the real data is stored in a file, but it's being mapped to RAM, so that you can access it as if it were in RAM. It will be brought in from disk when required.

This would generally be used for something where the real data is huge, and so wouldn't all fit comfortably in RAM.

Comment: thanks, So program text(code) is file-backed mapping is it right?

Comment: @raj2010 it's likely to be a large block of data rather than code.

Comment: can you elaborate with example?

Comment: @raj2010 Suppose you had an 8GB file representing location data for places around the world. You really wouldn't want to load the whole file into RAM. But it would be nice to be able to pretend it was in RAM, and access it without having to worry about loading in different bits... this is what mapping does for you.

Answer (score 0):

This can be understood as if the data that is stored in a file gets referred by some virtual space using which it can be read as if it was stored a part of the virtual memory or RAM.

> " File-backed mapping maps an area of the process's virtual memory to
>   files; i.e. reading those areas of memory causes the file to be read.
>   It is the default mapping type."

Reference : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap